# Toggle font awesome icon on click?

Tags: jquery, fonts, toggle, font-awesome

I'm trying to change the fa-bars icon with fa-times icon on click (and back). I looked all over for a similar solution, but I can't seem to get it right.

**HTML+jQuery**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="#" class="toggle-nav js-nav"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a>

<div class="nav-wrap">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.js-nav').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.menu').toggleClass('active');
        })
});
</script>
```

**[DEMO: navigation bar](http://jsbin.com/xulirapamo/edit?html,output)**

Thanks

Comment: Seems to work in the fiddle if you link properly to the stylesheet https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r8p0hs3b/50/

Comment: j08691 is correct in that your fiddle works with the proper stylesheet linking. You have a not http link, so it gets blocked, plus you should link to it in the resources.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed it too late...I linked it again. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following and let me know how you get on.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.js-nav').click(function(){
$(this).parent().find('.menu').toggleClass('active');
$(this).find('i.fa').removeClass('fa-bars').addClass('fa-times');
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks dru_ward, it works but it's not changing back to the fa-bars. How do I add this to the code?

Comment: Ahhh I just saw the (add back) my bad, try the following:  $( document ).ready(function() {         $('.js-nav').click(function(){    $(this).parent().find('.menu').toggleClass('active');  if($(this).find('i.fa').hasClass('fa-bars')) {  $(this).find('i.fa').removeClass('fa-bars').addClass('fa-times'); } else if($(this).find('i.fa').hasClass('fa-times')) { $(this).find('i.fa').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-bars'); }           })  })();